# Making Excel Worksheet a Class Module member

Tags: class, vba, excel, worksheet

I'm trying to create a class module to build some basic db functionality in a workbook. The problem I'm running into is attempting to add a worksheet as a class member. I keep getting "Invalid use of property" as an error.

My class declaration:

```
Option Explicit

Private pboolLock As Boolean
Private pintColCount, pintRowCount As Integer
Private pWorksheet As Excel.Worksheet

'Lock bit properties:
Property Get boolLock() As Boolean
    boolLock = pboolLock
End Property
Property Let boolLock(boollockval As Boolean)
    pboolLock = boollockval
End Property

'Utility properties- no sets
Property Get ColCount() As Integer
    ColCount = pintColCount
End Property
Property Get RowCount() As Integer
    RowCount = pintRowCount
End Property

'Worksheet specific props
Property Set dpDefine(ByRef wks As Worksheet)
    Set pWorksheet = wks
End Property
Property Get dpDefine() As Worksheet
    dpDefine = pWorksheet
End Property
```

Different module: Class instantiation:

```
Sub tryClass()
    Dim thisdp As New Cdatapage
    Dim iansTest As String

    iansTest = Sheets("typical datapage").Name
    'this works, so reference is being passed:
    MsgBox ("The name is " & iansTest)

    'this doesn't work:
    thisdp.dpDefine (Sheets("typical datapage"))
End Sub
```

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Its a `Set` property so you need to:

```
Set thisdp.dpDefine = Sheets("typical datapage")
```

Or if you change `dpDefine` to a `Let` you can;

```
thisdp.dpDefine = Sheets("xxx")
```

Comment: You can't define a property as a let property if the type involved is an object.  You'll get an "object not set" error.